# ADD COLUMN with forced DECIMAL type for computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, alter-table

I'm trying to alter a to add a new computed column but the final result is decimal without ... decimal (???)

I came up with

```
ALTER TABLE
  dbo.transaction_payment
ADD
  total_amount AS CAST(
    (CAST(amount_transac AS decimal(12, 2))) + (CAST(amount_tip AS decimal(12, 2))) AS decimal(12, 2)
  )
```

But the engine tells me that I got an error. I cast every value to don't have implicit type and lose precision and I cast the final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "alter" a computed column, so:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.transaction_payment
    ADD total_amount as (CONVERT(decimal(12, 2), amount_transac + amount_tip));
```

If it already exists, drop it first:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.transaction_payment
    DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS total_amount;
```

Comment: I got the error `SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'.`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Microsoft SQL Server (since you have dbo. in your code), you should UPDATE the column rather than ALTER it. You appear to be missing a set of brackets around your sum:

```
UPDATE dbo.transaction_payment
SET total_amount = CAST((CAST(amount_transac AS DECIMAL(12,2))) + (CAST(amount_tip AS decimal(12,2)))AS decimal(12,2))
```

Comment: I don't want to update since I wanted it to be an auto calculated column.
And yes it's MSQL